# Issue installing FLEXnet on ubuntu for program: Geneious

Tags: 12.04

Afternoon,

I can successful in my Geneious Pro software but when I am required to have FLEXnet installed for the licensing process.

The prompt I am given is :

To install FLEXnet on Linux, run the following command from your shell as root:  /home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service/install_fnp.sh "/home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service/linux64/FNPLicensingService"  When you have done this, you can activate your license in Geneious.

As Root:

root@Jon:/home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service# sh install_fnp.sh 
Unable to locate anchor service to install, please specify correctly on command line

also

root@Jon:/home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service/linux64# sh FNPLicensingService 
FNPLicensingService: 2: FNPLicensingService: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Anyone have further ideas? I tried to find the software online directly, that was no good either.

~Jon

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the full command:

```
/home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service/install_fnp.sh "/home/shep/Geneious/licensing_service/linux64/FNPLicensingService"
```

note that the bit in quotes is a parameter to the install_fnp.sh shell script.